# Twitter Bootstrap Non-Collapsable Navbar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've been building an application using Twitter Bootstrap v2.0.2 as the framework, and I've been running into trouble, because the navbar will always collapse when the window is less than x pixels.

Although this is a nice feature in theory, my menu isn't that long and doesn't ever need to collapse.  Is there any easy-ish way to do this?  I've read a few posts that state I can just change the responsive css file, but I haven't had any success in either finding what I need to change, or changing the wrong values for min and max width.

Is there a class I can use other than div.nav-collapse so I don't have to worry about it trying to auto-collapse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove all `*collapse` classes from your nav components.  They are all optional.

Comment: Here is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292521/best-way-to-use-bootstrap-3-navbar-without-responsive-collapse

Comment: And an even better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535289/bootstrap-3-disable-navbar-collapse