# Best way to use Bootstrap 3 Navbar without responsive collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to create a simple Navbar in Bootstrap 3 that doesn't collapse - responsive isn't necessary here because we just have a simple title on the left + button on the right.

My goal is to have the title + buttons always appear the same for all resolutions. Something like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
    </form>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title Here</a>

</div>
```

I've tried numerous combinations from the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). And [this post outlines how to use the new .nav-header classes](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/9403). I've tried duplicating the elements inside .nav-header - and also tried overriding the BS3 media query styles.

Is there an easier way to use the Navbar without collapsing?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The best way I could find is to use 2 `navbar-header` containers, and then use `pull-left` and `pull-right` since they aren't tied to any responsive media queries..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title Here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Button 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo on Bootply: http://bootply.com/74912

Comment: Works great - thanks for suggesting the .navbar-btn class too

Comment: Thanks! That really helped! Simplest solution I could find!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i only used the `navbar-header` and nothing else.

Basically, the navbar-header would help me easily get all the header css in there. Inside of it, i added a container and played around with my options for a similar case as yours.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="transient-header">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="transient-header-block clearfix">
                <h1 class="hide" href="/" style="color: #fff;">Primary</h1>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{> svgs/logos/_white_symbol}}</a>
                <div class="pull-right price">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-white-border contact-modal" href="#contactModal">
                        {{> svgs/_white_rupee_icon}}
                        {{product.price}}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```