# What is the structure of the Bootstrap 3's navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

While the Bootstrap documentation is very good, I am unable to understand the navbar structure from just one example in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). I am trying to understand what are the sub-components of the navbar and how to use them. As far as I can tell, there are two areas of the navbar: a header and a collapse area. The header seems to be the place to put a brand name (to the left) and the toggle button to the right. It also seems like the area that will be always shown. Collapse seems to be the area for everything else and will be collapsed for smaller widths.

1. Is this the correct understanding? Are there any other areas?
2. What is the purpose of container-fluid wrapper? What if this wrapper is removed?
3. What kind of elements can go in each area?
4. What if I don't need any collapsable section? Should I put everything in the header?
5. What if I need three non-collapsible sections: left, middle and right?

Please help.

P.S. While the Bootstrap docuentation is very good, I wish that the components would be documented using some sort of a diagram identifying the various subcomponents and their intended behaviour and use.

**Edit**
I found [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.htm) on the Bootstrap Navbar that has many more examples - it is really nice. I can probably derive the patterns from there, but it would be nice if someone could articulate them more explicitly. For example, the very first example in this tutorial has a div with class navbar-header followed by a div with no class and containing all the links. This makes me think that one can add as many divs in the navbar as needed, navbar-header and navbar-collapse are just special purpose sub-components.

Comment: all components are in docs too, they are [Dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns), [Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-forms). the first button tag you see, is the one that is shown when screen is small.

Comment: I assume you are answering bullet #3 of my question - thanks! I am still looking for answers to the other bullets. Perhaps I should reword my question to something like "how do I structure the navbar code for different use cases".

Comment: ok I will try to answwer your questions. 1) yes, 2)container fluid was added recently in last patch in bootstrap 3.0 it did not exist, it should be documented in last update 3) already answered, 4) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292521/best-way-to-use-bootstrap-3-navbar-without-responsive-collapse, 5) if you need 3 no collapsable secctions you can use classes like pull-right, pull-left, and col-md-offset-4 (check offset classes and adapt them to your needs)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Also please read my edit to the question. The examples in that link seem to use plain old divs. The link in your comment suggests adding toe navbar-headers though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @bto.rdz's advice, this was the solution I came up with for #5 navbar with left, middle and right sections:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 navbar-text">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Left</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 navbar-text text-center">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Middle</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 navbar-text text-right">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Right</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I figured that since there is a container-fluid inside the navbar, why not create a row with 3 columns for the left, middle and right links. This almost worked except that it was breaking at 768 pixels. I traced this to Bootstrap adding 15px left and right margins at that breakpoint. I overrode this behavior as follows and now I have the desired behavior at all browser widths.

```
.navbar-text {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```