# Bootstrap 3 - disable navbar collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, preventdefault

This is my simple navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top myfont" role="navigation">
    <div class="">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="assets/img/logo.png"/>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    Create 
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li data-match-route="/"><a href="#/page-one">Login</a></li>
        <li data-match-route="/"><a href="#/page-two/sub-a">Signup</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I just would like to prevent this to collapse, cause I don't need it, how to do?

I would like to avoid writing 300K lines of CSS for overriding the default styles.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

After close examining, not 300k lines but there are around 3-4 CSS properties that you need to override:

```css
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right!important;
}
```

And with this your menu won't collapse.

**[DEMO](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Ft4ym3%2Fembedded%2Fresult%2F)** (*[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ym3/)*)

**EXPLANATION**

The four CSS properties do the respective:

1. The default `.collapse` property in bootstrap hides the right-side of the menu for tablets(landscape) and phones and instead a toggle button is displayed to hide/show it. Thus this property overrides the default and persistently shows those elements.
2. For the right-side menu to appear on the same line along with the left-side, we need the left-side to be floating left.
3. This property is present by default in bootstrap but not on tablet(portrait) to phone resolution. You can skip this one, it's likely to not affect your overall navbar.
4. This keeps the right-side menu to the right while the inner elements (`li`) will follow the property 2. So we have left-side *float left* and right-side *float right* which brings them into one line.

Comment: I used just the 2nd and 4th css stanzas. Keeping or removing the 3rd stanza doesn't seem to change anything. The 1st stanza I don't need because I simply don't apply navbar-collapse or collapse. Why apply them and them when you don't want it to collapse?

Comment: @gwho Just added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: If it gets skinny enough, the floated left and floated right elements can wrap on each other (im talking about the `ul`s not the `li`s). Whats tue best way to prevent even this from happening?

Comment: If your only requirement is to prevent the UL/LI list becoming vertical, the 2nd CSS is all that is needed.

Comment: The `!important` statements are not necessary here, for me it works without. Try to avoid them whenever possible (!important).

Comment: this can be further improved by prefixing mentioned rules with a mix-in class, say .navbar-flat, so that behavior can be changed dynamically by appending mix-in class to nav container

Comment: Works fine BUT dropdowns look terrible with low resolutions

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz Dropdowns still change behaviour when < 768 px, they're displayed in the nav-bar (collapsed beahviour) inside of appearing in a floated white box (non-collapsed behaviour) as one would expect. And the dropdown title widens when clicked, forcing other elements to shift. Just add a dropdown in a navbar element and you'll see it by yourself.

Comment: I just wanted to say, I have been fighting with this for a couple hours and this saved my bacon!

Answer (score 24):

The nabvar will collapse on small devices. The point of collapsing is defined by `@grid-float-breakpoint` in variables. By default this will by before `768px`. For screens below the `768` pixels screen width, the navbar will look like:

[image]

It's possible to change the `@grid-float-breakpoint` in variables.less and recompile Bootstrap. When doing this you also will have to change `@screen-xs-max` in navbar.less. You will have to set this value to your new `@grid-float-breakpoint -1`. See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10465. This is needed to change navbar forms and dropdowns at the @grid-float-breakpoint to their mobile version too.

**[Easiest way is to customize bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables)**

find variable:

```
 @grid-float-breakpoint
```

which is set to `@screen-sm`, you can change it according to your needs. Hope it helps!

---

### For SAAS Users

add your custom variables like `$grid-float-breakpoint: 0px;` before the `@import "bootstrap.scss";`

Comment: this is really helpfull unfortunately i'm using the bootstrap CDN so i'm unable to customize the bootstrap main file, any tip on how to do this in a separated css file?

Comment: +1 for the @grid-float-breakpoint-variable on the bootstrap customization page, that did the trick for me!

Comment: For SASS users: just add your custom variables like `$grid-float-breakpoint: 0px;` before the `@import "bootstrap.scss";` line

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach that leaves the default collapse behavior unchanged while allowing a new section of navigation to always remain visible. Its an augmentation of `navbar`; `navbar-header-menu` is a CSS class I have created and is not part of Bootstrap proper.

Place this in the `navbar-header` element after `navbar-brand`:

```
<div class="navbar-header-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">I'm always visible</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Add this CSS:

```
.navbar-header-menu {
    float: left;
}

    .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
    }

        .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav > li {
            float: left;
        }

            .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav > li > a {
                padding-top: 15px;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
            }

        .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
            box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
        }

    .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-form {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

        .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-form > .form-group {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

    .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-left {
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-header-menu > .navbar-right {
        float: right !important;
    }

    .navbar-header-menu > *.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: -15px !important;
    }
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2txunqo/

Caveat: `navbar-right` can be used to sort elements visually but is not guaranteed to pull the element to the furthest right portion of the screen. The fiddle demonstrates that behavior with the `navbar-form`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to simply remove `collapse navbar-collapse` from the markup. Example with Bootstrap 3.3.7

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-atp">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-custom">
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="sidebar-btn"><span class="fa fa-bars">Toggle btn</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>Nav item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the less version, here is the line you need to change:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { /* Change this to 0 */
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me in Bootstrap 3.3.4:

CSS:

```
/*no collapse*/

.navbar-collapse.collapse.off {
    display: block!important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.off ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-nav.no-collapse>li,
.navbar-nav.no-collapse {
    float: left !important;
}

.navbar-right.no-collapse {
    float: right!important;
}
```

then add the **.no-collapse** class to each of the lists and the **.off** class to the main container. Here is an example written in jade:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
        .container-fluid
            .collapse.navbar-collapse.off
                ul.nav.navbar-nav.no-collapse
                    li
                        a(href='#' class='glyph')
                            i(class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign')
                ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.no-collapse
                    li.dropdown
                        a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-expanded='false')
                            | Tools
                            span.caret
                        ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu')
                            li
                                a(href='#') Tool #1
                    li
                        a(href='#')
                            | Logout
```