# Bootstrap 3 how to not stack nav-justified in smaller viewports

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap nav and I need to avoid stacking of it on smaller viewports so that it stays horizontal and does not stack.

Here is a example

HTML:

```
<div class="menuBar">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="menuItem">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="menuItem">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="menuItem">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuBar ul {
    text-align: justify;
}
.menuBar ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menuItem {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Extended version: http://jsfiddle.net/m5k93rwo/

What is the best way to do that? I suspect some play with data-toggle but, unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough to be sure how make it working well

Comment: maybe the answer to this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535289/bootstrap-3-disable-navbar-collapse

Comment: You don't play with data-toggle, it has nothing to do with it. If I understand, you don't want a mobile nav? You want not collapse because justified-nav looks bizarre in the collapse as it's not meant to go there?

Comment: Whatever you don't want to collapse don't put inside a .collapse

Comment: @ChaoticNadirs nope, it's not working with nav-justify which i am using

Comment: @Christina yes, that's correct. About collapsing... actually i don't use it directly here at all.

Comment: Do you mean you want to avoid stacking, you want to keep it horizontal?

Comment: @Christina yes, that's what i mean

Comment: Collapsing and stacking are different. I re-worded your question and answered it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this css after all your other css:

```
  .nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-justified > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

Comment: This does not normalize the borders (stacked tabs obviously have different borders than horizontally aligned tabs).