# Bootstrap Pills with Badges: Hide non-badge text on mobile

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi-step form hooked up with angular ui router, with a little bootstrap nav on top:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".amount">Step <span class="badge">1</span> Amount</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".card">Step <span class="badge">2</span> Payment</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".contact">Step <span class="badge">3</span> Contact</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".confirm">Step <span class="badge">4</span> Confirm</a></li>
</ul>
```

Looks slick on larger screens, but the amount of text in each pill causes them to occupy their own line on mobile-sized screens. I'd like instead for the non-badge content of each pill to disappear on small-sized screens, as per the screenie below.

I could do this quickly with extra span tags, but I'd like to know if there's a CSS-only solution that I could apply instead.

## Current Behavior:

[image: Current Behavior - pills take up their own line]

## Desired Behavior:

[image: Desired behavior: extraneous text is hidden on mobile]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the text you want to side in `<span>` elements that have the `.hidden-xs` class. That will make them not visible in small screens, e.g. smaller than 768px.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".amount"><span class="hidden-xs">Step </span><span class="badge">1</span><span class="hidden-xs"> Amount</span></a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".amount"><span class="hidden-xs">Step </span><span class="badge">2</span><span class="hidden-xs"> Amount</span></a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".amount"><span class="hidden-xs">Step </span><span class="badge">3</span><span class="hidden-xs"> Amount</span></a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".amount"><span class="hidden-xs">Step </span><span class="badge">4</span><span class="hidden-xs"> Amount</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, to disable the stacking you can add the following CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .nav-justified > li {
        display: inline;
    }
    .nav-justified > li {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

See [here](http://www.bootply.com/dHGFQ7K2MQ) a working sample.

Comment: Note: If you want to avoid stacking but keep the "justified" effect take a look in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26004988/2851870.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .hidden-xs and .visible-xs-* http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities like:

```
<!-- invisible in mobile -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified hidden-xs">
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".amount">Step <span class="badge">1</span> Amount</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".card">Step <span class="badge">2</span> Payment</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".contact">Step <span class="badge">3</span> Contact</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".confirm">Step <span class="badge">4</span> Confirm</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- visible only in mobile -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified visible-xs-*">
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class='col-xs-3'><a ui-sref=".amount"><span class="badge">1</span></a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class='col-xs-3'><a ui-sref=".card"><span class="badge">2</span></a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class='col-xs-3'><a ui-sref=".contact"><span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class='col-xs-3'><a ui-sref=".confirm"><span class="badge">4</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And add `class='col-xs-3'` to each `li` in mobile.

Hope it helps!