# how to prevent the collapse bootstrap-3 menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please, help
I do not need to collapse the menu on mobile devices
How to prevent the collapse bootstrap-3 menu?
I tried to find a solution, but did not find

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">           
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-6" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>               
            </div>
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-6" class="collapse navbar-collapse">                  
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style='margin-right:10px;'>         
            <li><a href='/add-your-car'><img style="height:25px; opacity:0.8;" src="/img/carcash.png"><br><?=MENU_1;?></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img src="/img/about.png"><br><?=MENU_2;?><span class="caret"></span></a>                
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick='return false;' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalLogin"><img src="/img/login.png"><br><?=MENU_3;?></a></li>
            <li><a id='reguser' onclick='return false;' href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAuth"><img src="/img/regg.png"><br><?=MENU_4;?></a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img src="/img/lang<?=$global_locale;?>.png"><br><?=MENU_10;?><span class="caret"></span></a>                
            </li>
         </ul>                
    </div>           
     </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your css file:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
    float: left !important;
}
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

The Forth class remove the burger button from mobile.

Answer found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535289/bootstrap-3-disable-navbar-collapse)

Comment: I guess this worked for you! Could you please accept this answer as correct?