# Twitter navbar change its height when the screen is resized

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

please look this three picture:

1) If all elements fit into navbar everithing is ok

[image]

2) If only central elements fit into navbar the height of navabar encrease automatically

[image]

3) If the page become more smaller is ok

[image]

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx">Gestione Azienda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Elenco commesse<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/elenco.aspx?societa=1">1</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/elenco.aspx?societa=2">2</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/elenco.aspx?societa=3">3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Gestisci commessa<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/1.aspx/#tab-1">1</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/2.aspx/#tab-2">2</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/3.aspx/#tab-3">3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Impostazioni<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/impostazioni.aspx">Impostazioni Generali</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/GestioneUtenti.aspx">Gestione utenti</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a id="A1" runat="server" href="~/ProgLavori.aspx" target="_blank">Programmazione lavori</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="http://" target="_blank">Posta</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu_logout" runat="server" onserverclick="logout">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu_login" runat="server" href="~/Default.aspx">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here you can find the code, if you try to resize the menu area you can see my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dabnd41/

Someone could help me??

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Bootstrap navbar-collapse.  There is a great explanation about how to do this here: [Bootstrap 3 - disable navbar collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535289/bootstrap-3-disable-navbar-collapse)

Comment: I need navbar-collapse enabled, because it can fit to mobile screen. Disabling it its like that http://jsfiddle.net/bos09162/.