# How to make Bootstrap navbar in mobile view like a normal menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.bootply.com/y1iaZwCCct

I'm using this menu in my website but couldn't change the default settings. I need a script in jQuery which makes two things to the menu in mobile-view.

1. Close when i click on a link.
2. Close when i click outside the menu.

I`m new to jQuery so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: I need a script that can do the above two things that i asked. I`m only able to close the menu when a link is clicked but not when clicked outside the menu.

Comment: i used data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in"  on anchor tags to close the menu when a link is clicked but i also want the menu to close when user click outside the menu

Comment: Have you searched for a solution? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764863/how-to-close-an-open-collapsed-navbar-when-clicking-outside-of-the-navbar-elemen)

Comment: yeah but still the open menu doesnt close when clicked outside the menu

Comment: Have you try to type in google before asking ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535289/bootstrap-3-disable-navbar-collapse

Comment: yeah i searched but couldn`t find exact solution but now i got the answer from the link @Phil gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND THE SOLUTION......

1. Use `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target=".in"` on `a`-tags or list element to close the menu when a link is clicked.
2. this code to close the menu when we clicked outside the menu

   ```
   $(document).click(function (event) {
       var clickover = $(event.target);
       var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");               
       var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");
       if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {      
           $navbar.collapse('hide');
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code also.. it works for me

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var container = $(".container-fluid");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
            }
        });

$(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

             $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');

  });
```